# How to delete ingested data when azure data factory pipeline run is cancelled?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Right now I have a Azure Data Factory pipeline that has 4 copy activities, all the copy activities are copying specific tables from a sql db to specific tables in psql. The pipeline is triggered with python code and I have a function that can cancel the pipeline run.

I want to implement a feature when the pipeline run is cancelled all the data that has been copied into my psql will deleted. But I have no idea how. I looked up the delete activity, but it does not support psql.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

I have looked into the delete activity and lookup activity. The lookup activity seems promising, but I dont know how I can only trigger that activity when the pipeline is canceled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you cancel a pipeline run, no other further activities within the same pipeline can be processed. So there is no way wherein you can delete the data that has been copied into sink once you cancel a pipeline as cancelling is an abrupt stop.
And since ADF/Synapse pipelines copy data in batches and do not support transaction, the best way for you would be initially load data into staging tables and then load them into final table bound with transaction.

Also, in case if you want to delete the data in final tables as well post cancellation, you would have to write your own custom logic wherein

1. create a log table that would log the end status of the pipeline and copy the pipelinerunid as a audit column in your table for the records that are copied.
2. Integrate Log analytics with ADF and in case if there is any pipeline cancellation run, get the pipelinerunid and validate it with log table and then trigger a lookup activity to delete the rows with the pipelinerunid

Comment: Thank you @Nandan! I was really fixated to just have one pipeline that will do everything. But this makes a lot more sense triggerring another pipeline when the pipeline is cancelled